# Query a Map containing a string saved in Cloud Firestore with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've a problem with a query condition. I would like to query a string inside an array that's also inside a map. I manage to receive the information complet without the where condition but when I do this condition I've an error.

[image]

My function to retrieve all information

[image]

My array with a map inside

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If `category` is the only value inside the `produits` array items, you can check for its existence with `array-contains`:

```
collectionRef.where('produits', arrayContains({ 'categorie': 'Alimentation' }))
```

---

If there are more properties for the array item, you will need to specify all of them in the call to `arrayContains`. There is no way to query for a subset of the array item.

In such cases, a common workaround is to add a extra array field to the document with just the property values you want to query for. For example:

```
produitsCategories: ['Alimentation', '...']
```

With that field in place you can then query it with:

```
collectionRef.where('produitsCategories', arrayContains('Alimentation'))
```